# How to setup Maven Archetype to generate module project at same level as parent project?

Tags: maven, maven-archetype

I want to create a maven archetype which should generate child module projects at the same level as parent project. So the structure will look like -

```
- parent
   |_ pom.xml
   |_ <rest-of-the-files>
- child1
   |_ pom.xml
   |_ <rest-of-the-files>
- child2
   |_ pom.xml
   |_ <rest-of-the-files>
```

The parent pom.xml will have modules like -

```
<modules>
    <module>../child1</module>
    <module>../child2</module>
</modules>
```

Is there any way to achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

See [answer to *Error installing a multimodule archetype created with mvn archetype:create-from-project*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20603513/1744774):

> It looks like the archetype plugin doesn't support flat layout for multi-module projects.

You can use the following (agreed, a bit cumbersome) workaround:

1. Create your projects as:

   ```
   +- parent
      +- pom.xml
      +- ...
      |
      +- child1
      |  +- pom.xml
      |  +- ...
      | 
      +- child2
         +- pom.xml
         +- ...
   ```
2. Create another project in `parent/src/main/resources`:

   ```
   +- parent
      +- pom.xml
      +- ...
      +- src
         +- main
            +- resources   
               +- pom.xml
   ```

   with the POM like:

   ```xml
    ...
    <artifactId>move-modules</artifactId>
    ...

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-antrun-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.0.0</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <phase>initialize</phase>
                        <configuration>
                            <target>
                                <echo level="info">Moving modules...</echo>
                                <move file="../../../../child1" tofile="../../../../../child1" failonerror="false" />
                                <move file="../../../../child2" tofile="../../../../../child2" failonerror="false" />
                            </target>
                        </configuration>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>run</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
   ```
3. Generate, install/deploy and use your archetype according to [Maven Archetype Plugin, Advanced Usage/Archetype creation](http://maven.apache.org/archetype/maven-archetype-plugin/advanced-usage.html).
4. `new/project/created/above/src/main/resources/move-modules $ mvn initialize`
5. Adapt `<module>`s in your `parent` POM:

   ```xml
    <modules>
        <module>../child1</module>
        <module>../child2</module>
    </modules>
   ```